# Sort list of list in Python according to a specific column

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], 
     [3, 5, 4], 
     [9, 8, 7]]
```

I want to sort corresponding elements in each sublist so that the *middle sublist* would be in descending order, which would result in:

```
l = [[2, 3, 1],
     [5, 4, 3], 
     [8, 7, 9]]
```

The second list is now descending: `[5, 4, 3]`. Essentially, I want reorder the vertical columns in that 2D representation. It seems like an easy task, but I had difficulties finding a solution.

So far I tried:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))
```

which didn't change anything and I tried

```
print(l.sort(key = lambda row: (row[1])))
```

which gave None.

Comment: Please show your code for this and explain what difficulties you are having.

Comment: The key is `key`. Read the documentation.  https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: `sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reversed=True)`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That's not quite right. reversed should be reverse

Comment: The result, the explanation and the dupe don't match each other. Things are not quite right here.

Comment: Guys, this isn't a dupe (I thought so too).  What he wants to do is sort the columns of a 2d matrix by their values in the second row, descending.

Comment: I added what I tried. In the resulting list, the 5 is in the first position now, so is the 2 from the first list and the 8 from the third list. I described 1, 3, 9 and 2, 5, 8 and 3, 4, 7 as rows.

Comment: Yep, I've voted to reopen this.

Comment: `sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))` doesn't change anything - it returns a *new* list. As for `print(l.sort(key = lambda row: (row[1])))`, the reason why get `None` is that `l.sort` modifies the original list and returns `None`...

Comment: `indices = [i for i, x in sorted(enumerate(l[1]), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)]` `getter = itemgetter(*indices)` `result = [list(getter(sublist)) for sublist in l]`

Comment: If you use `pprint` on that structure, then you pretty much will notice that `[3, 5, 4]` is a **row** not column; it is not natural at all to think them as columns really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attempts you made will sort by values in the second column, but you want to sort by values in the second row. So transpose the list, sort by column, then transpose back.

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]]
>>> transposed_l = zip(*l)
>>> transposed_l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
>>> l = zip(*transposed_l)
>>> l
[(2, 3, 1), (5, 4, 3), (8, 7, 9)]
```

---

Bonus tip: your `print(l.sort(...` approach printed `None` because `sort` doesn't return anything, it sorts in-place. So you should instead do `l.sort(...)` and then `print(l)`. Conversely, your `sorted(l, ...)` attempt didn't appear to do anything because it *doesn't* sort in-place, and instead returns a brand new list. I'm guessing you did `sorted(l, ...)` and then `print(l)` and were surprised to see nothing changed. You might instead do `l = sorted(l, ...)` and then `print(l)`. (although just using `sort` would be more idiomatic)